# Meteor synchronus content for each client

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, three.js, synchronization

I'm trying to make a multiplayer snake in three.js with meteor, it works well for one player to only control one snake (though we have only 3 specified users who can control one out of 3 snakes for now)

now the problem is, that you can't see the other players movement on your screen and they can't see yours, it's like everyone has their own game.

My HTML looks like this: (client.html)

```
<div>
{{> loginButtons align="right"}}
{{> spiel}}
    <div id="msg">
        {{> messages}}
    </div>
    <div id="inp">
        {{> input}}
    </div>
</div>
```

the div with the game in it is the template 'spiel'

```
<template name="spiel">
    <div id="container"></div>
</template>
```

i fill the container with  (main.js in my client folder)

```
Template.spiel.rendered = function(){
    init();
    addSchlange();
    addSchlange2();
    addSchlange3();
    animate();
}
```

and the code i call there looks like this (test.js in a lib folder in my client folder)
 i don't know what could cause the problem so i'll post the whole code (don't hate me for that ^^)

```
var camera, scene, renderer;

            init =function (){
                //Allgemeines
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xbbbbbb, 2000, 10000 );
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);

                camera.position.y =50;
                camera.rotation.x=-1.571;

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
                renderer.gammaInput = true;
                renderer.gammaOutput = true;
                renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color, 1 );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                var container = document.getElementById("container");
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                var ggeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 500, 500 );
                var gmaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { emissive: 0xbbbbbb } );
                var ground = new THREE.Mesh( ggeometry, gmaterial );
                ground.position.set( 0, -250, 0 ); 
                ground.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
                scene.add( ground );

                ground.receiveShadow = true;

                // LIGHTS
                var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
                scene.add( ambient );


                var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xebf3ff, 1.6 );
                light.position.set( 0, 140, 500 ).multiplyScalar( 1.1 );
                scene.add( light );

                light.castShadow = true;

                light.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
                light.shadowMapHeight = 2048;

                var d = 390;

                light.shadowCameraLeft = -d;
                light.shadowCameraRight = d;
                light.shadowCameraTop = d * 1.5;
                light.shadowCameraBottom = -d;

                light.shadowCameraFar = 3500;
                light.shadowCameraVisible = true;

                var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x497f13, 1 );
                light.position.set( 0, -1, 0 );
                scene.add( light );


            }

            addSchlange = function () {
                var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
                var callbackModel = function( geometry, materials ) { 
                        Kopf1 = new THREE.Mesh (geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
                        Kopf1.scale.set( 1.5,1.5, 1.5 );
                        Kopf1.position.set(-1.5,0,0);

                        var xDirection = Kopf1.position.x;
                        var yDirection = Kopf1.position.y;
                        pivot1 = new THREE.Object3D();
                        pivot1.add(Kopf1);
                        scene.add(pivot1); 
                    }; 
                loader.load( 'SchlangeKOPFnoTEX.js', callbackModel ); 
                Schlange1 = new Array();        
            }

            addSchlange2 = function () {
                var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
                var callbackModel = function( geometry, materials ) { 
                        Kopf2 = new THREE.Mesh (geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
                        Kopf2.scale.set( 1.5,1.5, 1.5 );
                        Kopf2.position.set(-3,0,-9.75);

                        var xDirection = Kopf2.position.x;
                        var yDirection = Kopf2.position.y;
                        pivot2 = new THREE.Object3D();
                        pivot2.add(Kopf2);
                        scene.add(pivot2); 
                    }; 
                loader.load( 'SchlangeKOPF2.js', callbackModel ); 
                Schlange2 = new Array();    
                Change2 = new Array();

            }

            addSchlange3 = function(){
                var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
                var callbackModel = function( geometry, materials ) { 
                        Kopf3 = new THREE.Mesh (geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
                        Kopf3.scale.set( 1.5,1.5, 1.5 );
                        Kopf3.position.set(-3.25,0,9.5);

                        var xDirection = Kopf2.position.x;
                        var yDirection = Kopf2.position.y;
                        pivot3 = new THREE.Object3D();
                        pivot3.add(Kopf3);
                        scene.add(pivot3);  
                    }; 
                loader.load( 'SchlangeKOPF3.js', callbackModel );       
            }



            var changeDirection = "D";
            var lastPOS = "D";
            var changeDirection2 = "D";
            var lastPOS2 = "D";
            var changeDirection3 = "D";
            var lastPOS3 = "D";


            animate = function(){
                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            $(window).bind('keyup', function (event) {
                var keycode;
                keycode = event.keyCode;

        // SCHLANGE 1
            if(Meteor.user().username == 'Babsi'){
                if(keycode == 65){
                    lastPOS = changeDirection;
                    if(lastPOS !="D"){

                    changeDirection = "A";

                    }
                                    }
                if(keycode == 83){
                    lastPOS = changeDirection;
                    if(lastPOS != "W"){

                    changeDirection = "S";

                    }

                }
                if(keycode == 68){
                    lastPOS = changeDirection;
                    if(lastPOS != "A"){

                    changeDirection = "D";

                    }

                }
                if(keycode == 87){
                    lastPOS = changeDirection;
                    if(lastPOS != "S"){

                    changeDirection = "W";

                    }

                }
                }
        //SCHLANGE 2
        if(Meteor.user().username == 'Jacky'){
                if(keycode == 65){
                    lastPOS2 = changeDirection2;
                    if(lastPOS2 !="D"){

                    changeDirection2 = "A";
                    }
                                    }
                if(keycode == 83){
                    lastPOS2 = changeDirection2;
                    if(lastPOS2 != "W"){

                    changeDirection2 = "S";

                    }
                }
                if(keycode == 68){
                    lastPOS2 = changeDirection2;
                    if(lastPOS2 != "A"){

                    changeDirection2 = "D";

                    }

                }
                if(keycode == 87){
                    lastPOS2 = changeDirection2;
                    if(lastPOS2 != "S"){

                    changeDirection2 = "W";
                    }

                }
            }
        //SCHLANGE 3
        if(Meteor.user().username == 'Manu'){
                if(keycode == 65){
                    lastPOS3 = changeDirection3;
                    if(lastPOS3 !="D"){

                    changeDirection3 = "A";
                    }
                                    }
                if(keycode == 83){
                    lastPOS3 = changeDirection3;
                    if(lastPOS3 != "W"){

                    changeDirection3 = "S";
                    }
                }
                if(keycode == 68){
                    lastPOS3 = changeDirection3;
                    if(lastPOS3 != "A"){

                    changeDirection3 = "D";

                    }

                }
                if(keycode == 87){
                    lastPOS3 = changeDirection3;
                    if(lastPOS3 != "S"){

                    changeDirection3 = "W";

                    }

                }
                }
            });
                if(typeof pivot1 !='undefined') {
                    if(changeDirection == "A"){
                        pivot1.position.x -= 0.2;   
                        pivot1.rotation.y = 1.571*2;
                        if(pivot1.position.x<=-37){
                            pivot1.position.x=40;
                            pivot1.position.x -= 0.2;
                        }
                    }
                    if(changeDirection == "D"){
                        pivot1.position.x += 0.2;   
                        pivot1.rotation.y = 0;
                        if(pivot1.position.x>=37){
                            pivot1.position.x=-40;
                            pivot1.position.x -= 0.2;
                        }


                    }
                    if(changeDirection == "S"){
                        pivot1.position.z += 0.2;
                        pivot1.rotation.y = -1.571; 
                        if(pivot1.position.z>=38){
                            pivot1.position.z=-38;
                            pivot1.position.z -= 0.2;
                        }


                    }
                    if(changeDirection == "W"){
                        pivot1.position.z -= 0.2;
                        pivot1.rotation.y = 1.571;  
                        if(pivot1.position.z<=-38){
                            pivot1.position.z=38;
                            pivot1.position.z -= 0.2;
                        }


                    }
                }
                if(typeof pivot2 !='undefined') {
                    if(changeDirection2 == "W"){
                        pivot2.position.z -= 0.2;
                        pivot2.rotation.y = 1.571;  
                        if(pivot2.position.z<=-38){
                            pivot2.position.z=38;
                            pivot2.position.z -= 0.2;
                        }

                    }
                    if(changeDirection2 == "S"){
                        pivot2.position.z += 0.2;
                        pivot2.rotation.y = -1.571; 
                        if(pivot2.position.z>=38){
                            pivot2.position.z=-38;
                            pivot2.position.z -= 0.2;
                        }
                    }
                    if(changeDirection2 == "D"){
                        pivot2.position.x += 0.2;   
                        pivot2.rotation.y = 0;
                        if(pivot2.position.x>=37){
                            pivot2.position.x=-40;
                            pivot2.position.x -= 0.2;
                        }
                    }
                    if(changeDirection2 == "A"){
                        pivot2.position.x -= 0.2;   
                        pivot2.rotation.y = 1.571*2;
                        if(pivot2.position.x<=-37){
                            pivot2.position.x=40;
                            pivot2.position.x -= 0.2;
                        }

                    }
                }
                if(typeof pivot3 !='undefined') {
                    if(changeDirection3 == "W"){
                        pivot3.position.z -= 0.2;
                        pivot3.rotation.y = 1.571;  
                        if(pivot3.position.z<=-38){
                            pivot3.position.z=38;
                            pivot3.position.z -= 0.2;
                        }
                    }   
                    if(changeDirection3 == "S"){
                        pivot3.position.z += 0.2;
                        pivot3.rotation.y = -1.571; 
                        if(pivot3.position.z>=38){
                            pivot3.position.z=-38;
                            pivot3.position.z -= 0.2;
                        }
                    }
                    if(changeDirection3 == "D"){
                        pivot3.position.x += 0.2;   
                        pivot3.rotation.y = 0;
                        if(pivot3.position.x>=37){
                            pivot3.position.x=-40;
                            pivot3.position.x -= 0.2;
                        }
                    }
                    if(changeDirection3 == "A"){
                        pivot3.position.x -= 0.2;   
                        pivot3.rotation.y = 1.571*2;
                        if(pivot3.position.x<=-37){
                            pivot3.position.x=40;
                            pivot3.position.x -= 0.2;
                        }

                    }

                }
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            }
```

Comment: try wrapping all of your functions in a `Tracker.autorun` so it looks like this `Template.spiel.rendered = function () { Tracker.autorun( function() { init(); addSchalange(); ....}) }` . I use this when I am using d3.js with meteor.

Comment: that changend nothing :/

Comment: is this a meteor question or a three.js question? I don't see any code that synchronizes the data (presumably the position of the snake) across clients.

Comment: Probably a meteor question, we just learned it. I did not know i had to add something to sync it, i googled a lot but couldn't find anything..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor syncs *data* across clients. If you want each client to see the position of the other clients’ snakes, you’ll need to store those positions in a collection that all clients are subscribed to.

In common code:

```
Snakes = new Meteor.Collection('snakes');
```

And then in your `rendered` callback, you’ll need to insert or update a document in `Snakes`. Set that document’s `_id` to a variable, and then inside your animation code you should call something like `Snakes.update(_id, {position: newPosition})`. Don’t call it 60 times per second; once or twice per second is probably the most that the connection can handle. These updates are automatically synced to the other clients; use an `observeChanges` listener to handle the updates on the other clients and tell Three.js how to update the positions of the snakes.

See also the [Meteor Streams](http://arunoda.github.io/meteor-streams/) package. It lets you do basically the same thing but without needing to write to the database; the “updates” really just become events that are fired across all connected clients. Therefore it might be much more performant for your use case, which I’d imagine would be a prime consideration. Even though the website says the project is abandoned, I’ve used Meteor Streams on current (Meteor 1.0.3.2) projects, and it works just fine.